# Git rebasing one branch onto another excluding merges up from parent

Tags: git, rebase

I want to rebase a feature branch onto another feature branch that has permanently diverged from master. There are too many commits to cherry-pick so I thought a rebase would be the way to go but I don't know how to exclude the changes to master after D.

Essentially I want to:

Start with:

```
      E-F-G-H [feature_2]
     /
A-B-D-I-K [master]
   \   \ \
    C-G-J-L-M-N [feature_1]
```

End with:

```
              G-M-N [feature_1]
             /
      E-F-G-H [feature_2]
     /
A-B-D-I-K [master]
```

I've tried the following but it appears to apply commits J and L as well

```
git checkout feature_1
git rebase --onto feature_2 B
```

Comment: So you just want to rewrite your history of `feature_1`? You can try [rebase interactive](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History), e.g. `rebase --interactive HEAD~6`.

Comment: rebasing is a glorified cherry-pick when you look inside.... so it's not like a rebase can "automagically" get rid of conflicts that happened when you tried cherry-picking. And they are probably coming up when applying M and N, right? That is because those changes work over changes that are coming from the merges in J and L... so there's no way around it, apparently... unless you bring some of that in the rebase/cherry-pick that you will carry out.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure `master` is the "upstream" for the rebase operation - this is what decides what commits will be rewritten - and then use the `--onto` argument as you noted.

```
git checkout feature-1
git rebase --onto feature-2 master
```

or the single-command shorthand

```
git rebase --onto feature-2 master feature-1
```